# error in predict glmer object

Tags: r

I am trying to `predict` a `glmer` object with an argument `newparams` like this:

```
library(lme4)

    set.seed(123)
    df<-data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 50, T),
                   y=rbinom(50, 1, 0.3),
                   x1=rbinom(50, 1, 0.5),
                   x2=as.integer(rnorm(50, 40, 5)))
    df<-df[order(df$id),]

    fit<-glmer(y~x1+x2+(1|id), data=df, binomial)
    predict(fit, newparams=list(theta=getME(fit, "theta"), beta=fixef(fit)))
    Error in predict(fit, newparams = list(theta = getME(fit, "theta"), 
unused argument (newparams = list(theta = getME(fit, "theta"), beta = fixef(fit)))
```

May somebody here know what's the reason?

Comment: This is a surprising error.  Can you give the results of `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: @agstudy's version works for me on MacOS as well as on Linux (although I'm using the devel version on Linux and have only tried with 1.1-5 on MacOS ...)

Comment: works with 1.1-6 on MacOS too.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! It seems the error gone after I freshly started R this morning. I bet some background workspaces may have caused that error but I don't know specifically what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set `newdata` argument. This works fine :

```
predict(fit, newdata=df,
  newparams=list(theta=getME(fit, "theta"), beta=fixef(fit)))
```

**PS**

using your code I get a different error:

```
Error: inherits(fr, "data.frame") is not TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! but I still have the same error as I posted. My lme4 version is lme4_1.1-6. Platform:x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit).

Comment: I have the same lme4_1.1-6 . I guess it is a MAC problem! maybe you should contact the maintainer.

Comment: I do confirm your error, that's something I should probably fix (although the workaround is fairly easy).  Feel free to add a new issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues in case I don't get around to it ...